# HTML Form Text Input offset left, top, width value problem

Tags: javascript, html, forms, text, input

I cannot get offset (left, top, width) values of form text input.

For the code below, I want a div called "divFrm" move next to the text area in the form. But I cannot get offset values correctly.

```
<form id="frmID" method="post">
<input type="text" id="txtID" name="txtName" value=""/>
</form>

var frmTxt = document.getElementById("txtID");
var divFrm = document.getElementById("divFrm");
divFrm.style.left = frmTxt.offsetLeft + frmTxt.offsetWidth + "px";
divFrm.style.top = frmTxt.offsetTop + "px";
```

Is there a way ?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting position:absolute; for your div element. It worked for me, the div being inside the same container as your form element.

HTH.